# negative or unfeasible result with Cplex

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to solve a LP with Cplex. the variables are 3 and 4 dimentinal positive arrays. like this :

```
`typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray> IloNumVarArray2;
 typedef IloArray<IloNumVarArray2> IloNumVarArray3;
 IloNumVarArray3 A(env, J) ; 
for (int j=0; j<J; j++){
    A[j]=IloNumVarArray2(env,T);
     for ( int t=0; t<T; t++){
      A[j][t]=IloNumVarArray(env,S,0,IloInfinity,ILOFLOAT);
         }}`
```

Cplex gives negative values for A. I don't understand why it is just not unfeasible.

Comment: You use the [constructor of `IloNumVarArray` that creates `S` individual `IloNumVar` objects](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.ide.help%2Frefcppopl%2Fhtml%2Fclasses%2FIloNumVarArray.html). This part has nothing to do with model infeasiblity. Can you post more code?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. the code is quite long. Cplex gives values very close to zero like -2.5485e-014, but not zero. I still don't understand this kind of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that every machine (and therefore application) produces correct output up to a certain level of tolerance.

The long answer, taken by the [`CPLEX` manual](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r2/index.jsp?topic=/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/CPLEX/_pubskel/CPLEX934.html) section on feasibility tolerance:

> Specifies the feasibility tolerance, that is, the degree to which
>   values of the basic variables calculated by the simplex method may
>   violate their bounds. Feasibility influences the selection of an
>   optimal basis and can be reset to a higher value when a problem is
>   having difficulty maintaining feasibility during optimization. You may
>   also wish to lower this tolerance after finding an optimal solution if
>   there is any doubt that the solution is truly optimal. If the
>   feasibility tolerance is set too low, CPLEX may falsely conclude that
>   a problem is infeasible. If you encounter reports of infeasibility
>   during Phase II of the optimization, a small adjustment in the
>   feasibility tolerance may improve performance.
>
> **Values**
>
> Any number from `1e-9` to `1e-1`; default: `1e-06`.

In simpler words, any infeasibility with magnitude smaller than `1e-06` is ignored by `CPLEX`. Since `|-2.5485e-014| < 1e-06`, `CPLEX` thinks that the solution is feasible.

You can set the feasibility tolerance to a difference number by changing the value of `EpRHS` for the `C++` API. [This example shows how you do it:](http://leonardo.rice.edu/~cecilia/research/manuals/cplex90/html/gscplex/cplusStart18.html)

```
IloModel model(env, "chvatal");          // Instantiates the model
IloCplex cplex(model);                   // Instantiates a CPLEX instance
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::SimDisplay, 2); // Changes SimDisplay, no idea whats this:)
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::RootAlg, IloCplex::Network); // Solves the LP with the Network solver
```

So in your case you should do something like

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::EpRHS, 1e-9)
```

Note that what you set has to be in the range [`1e-9, 1e-1`].. So it is not possible to go as accurate as `1e-14`, meaning that the result you get will be the same.

The even longer and more elaborate answer is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). It won't solve your issues, and it is a heavy read, but give it a go when you have some time - its fun!